# why var.name[i] in this code is printing stationto value

Tags: c, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
float final(float);
```

// structure to declare variables to be used in code.

```
struct tag
{
    int n;
    int age[50];
    int dist;
    char name[1][50];
    char stfrom[50];
    char stto[50];



}var;

void main()
{
    int i;
    float apcost,f;
    char str[50];
    char name[10][50];

    printf("Enter the number of tickets:\n");
    scanf(" %d",&var.n);// Total number of tickets

    for(i=0;i<var.n;i++)// This loop will run as many number of tickets.
    {
       // taking inputs of names with spaces and ages.
        printf("Enter name:\n");
        scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",name[i]);
        strcpy(var.name[i], name[i]);

        printf("Enter age:\n");
        scanf(" %d",&var.age[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEnter Station from:\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",var.stfrom);
    printf("Enter Station to:\n");
    scanf(" %[^\n]%*c",var.stto);

    printf("Enter the distance:\n");
    scanf(" %d",&var.dist);

    apcost = (var.dist * 3) * var.n;

    f = final(apcost);

    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("---------------The Final Bill-------------------------\n\n\n");

    printf("Number of tickets purchased:%d\n\n",var.n);

    printf("Names and ages of persons respectively:\n");
    for(i=0;i<var.n;i++)
    {
        puts(var.name[i]); //Here the station is getting printed instead of name.
        printf("\n%d\n",var.age[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\nStation From:");
    puts(var.stfrom);

    printf("\n\nStation to:");
    puts(var.stto);

    printf("\n\nTotal cost of tickets:%f\n\n",apcost);

    printf("--------------------\n");
    printf("The final cost after adding 12% tax:%f\n",f);
}

float final(float apcost)
{
    float j,k;
    j= (0.12 * apcost);
    k= apcost + j;

    return k;
}
```

When I am running the code, and entering the number of tickets as 2, the second name I am entering is not printing in the final bill, instead of that var.stto is printing.

Comment: You are declaring var.name as just 1 string (char name[1][50];).  When you try to load more than 1 string in it is instead copying into the next available block of memory, var.stfrom.

Comment: Is age supposed to be an array of 50 integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your struct definition:

```
struct tag
{
    int n;
    int age[50];
    int dist;
    char name[1][50];
    char stfrom[50];
    char stto[50];
}var;
```

The definition for name is statically defined to hold 1 name, and your code is accessing `stfrom` when it tries to write to `name[2]`. To fix this you'll need to make `name` a dynamic variable (making it array size 0) and using `malloc` to allocate the correct amount of space for the struct.
For example:

```
struct tag
{
    int n;
    int age[50];
    int dist;
    char stfrom[50];
    char stto[50];
    char name[][50];
};
```

...

```
struct tag *var = malloc(sizeof(struct tag) + 50*num);
```

where `num` is the number of tickets to buy

Comment: `char name[0][50]` is illegal in Standard C. However you can write `char name[][50];` and then allocate as you suggested.

Comment: Changed, however it is valid in GNU C.